# Fields not appear in database of Firebase Android Studio

Tags: java, android, firebase-realtime-database, database-connection

I have a problem about showing data to Firebase

Here is my RegisterActivity

```
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_register);


        mAuth= FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
        progressDialog = new  ProgressDialog (this);

        registerName = (TextInputLayout) findViewById(R.id.user_name_register);
        registerEmail = (TextInputLayout) findViewById(R.id.user_email_register);
        registerPassword = (TextInputLayout) findViewById(R.id.user_password_register);
        btnAlreadyhaveaccount = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_alreadyhaveaccount);
        btnCreateaccount = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_create);

        btnCreateaccount.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                String name =  registerName.getEditText().getText().toString();
                String email = registerEmail.getEditText().getText().toString();
                String password = registerPassword.getEditText().getText().toString();
                if(!TextUtils.isEmpty(name)||!TextUtils.isEmpty(email)||!TextUtils.isEmpty(password))
                {
                    progressDialog.setTitle("Creating");
                    progressDialog.setMessage("Please wait !!!");
                    progressDialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);
                    progressDialog.show();
                    register_user (name,email,password);
                }

            }
        });

    }

    private void register_user(final String name,  String email,  String password) {
        mAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                if(task.isSuccessful())
                {

                   FirebaseUser current_user  = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
                    String uid = current_user.getUid();

                    mDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Users").child(uid);

                    HashMap<String,String> userMap = new HashMap<>();
                    userMap.put("name",name);
                    userMap.put("status","status");
                    userMap.put("image","default");
                    mDatabase.setValue(userMap).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
                            if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                         progressDialog.dismiss();
                         Intent intent = new Intent(RegisterActivity.this, LoginActivity.class);
                         intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK|Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
                         startActivity(intent);
                         finish();

                            }
                        }
                    });*/
                    }
                else
                {
                    progressDialog.hide();
                    Toast.makeText(RegisterActivity.this, "Error . Please check the form and try again  ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
        });
    }
```

I have connected to FireBase and checked it . My data when i register , i could see in Authentication , but in Database it is empty

In my App then I register, it just shows Dialog Creating but cannot be done

When I remove all the code about the database , like this, it becomes normal, the dialog runs then end fast

```
 if(task.isSuccessful())
         {     
         progressDialog.dismiss();
         Intent intent = new Intent(RegisterActivity.this, LoginActivity.class);
         intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK|Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
         startActivity(intent);
          finish();
          }
                else
                {
                    progressDialog.hide();
                    Toast.makeText(RegisterActivity.this, "Error . Please check the form and try again  ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
```

I have restarted firebase , rebuilt my app , logout firebase then login again and connect again , still cannot solve the problem

Here Log

```
D/FirebaseAuth: Notifying id token listeners about user ( FddFnHAN5NeH2Wv0vVGt9zolL8n1 ).
    Notifying auth state listeners about user ( FddFnHAN5NeH2Wv0vVGt9zolL8n1 ).
D/FirebaseApp: Notifying auth state listeners.
    Notified 0 auth state listeners.
W/RepoOperation: setValue at /Users/FddFnHAN5NeH2Wv0vVGt9zolL8n1 failed: DatabaseError: Permission denied
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> failed: DatabaseError: Permission denied

Your database rules are not set to public or for authenticated users, set them to either one of the two in order to write/read

For not authenticated users

```
  {
      "rules": {
          ".read": true,
          ".write": true
      }
    }
```

For authenticated users

```
 {
  "rules": {
    ".read": "auth != null",
    ".write": "auth != null"
  }
}
```

Comment: Tks for saving my  Diploma Project , i fixed it , tks again

Comment: Glad it worked :) can you mark the answer as correct ? Thanks @NhânHồ

Comment: Hi @Gastón Saillén , i have a problem when i use FirebaseUI , hope u read this comment then check my profile to see my problem :D , unless u can , i still happy :D